# Why does this code get stuck in an endless loop?

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

```
void sort(int *ptr, int N);

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 15, 46, 34, 65, 23, 564, 76, 2, 3, 45 };
    int i = 0;
    int *ptr = &numbers;
    sort(ptr, sizeof(numbers));
    while (*ptr != '\n')
    {
        printf("%d\t", &ptr + i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}

void sort(int *ptr, int N)
{
    int i = 0;
    int last_i = N;
    int temp = 0;
    while (last_i > 0)
        for (i = 0; i < last_i; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i] > ptr[i + 1])
            {
                temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                ptr[i + 1] = temp;
            }
            last_i--;
        }
}
```

Tried to quickly throw a bubble sort together and move on, but it's
- Stuck in an endless loop
- Printing out the memory addresses instead of integers as I want it to

Where did I screw up?

**EDIT1**: Current state of the code:

```
void sort(int *ptr, int N);

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 15, 46, 34, 65, 23, 564, 76, 2, 3, 45 };
    int *ptr = numbers;
    sort(ptr, (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])));
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])); i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}

void sort(int *ptr, int N)
{
    int i = 0;
    int last_i = N;
    int temp = 0;
    while (last_i > 0)
        for (i = 0; i < last_i; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i] > ptr[i + 1])
            {
                temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                ptr[i + 1] = temp;
            }
            last_i--;
        }
}
```

Now gotta fix the `sort()`. "Add some more details" stackoverflow really doesn't want me to get back to fixing my problems as it won't let me post this edit and move on ;-;

Comment: Did you look at [warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/68Mjbfov6)? `int* ptr = &numbers;` is throwing one.

Comment: `sizeof(numbers)` gives the size in _bytes_ .. looks like you want the number of items in the array, which is `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` or something equivalent.

Comment: `&ptr` is a `int**` type, you need an `int` type if you're trying to print the items in the array, do `printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);` instead, where `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`.

Comment: So I changed some things and now it looks like this https://godbolt.org/z/WaGx1vjTq Not giving me Errors/Warnings in VS22, yet not working

Comment: the condition `*ptr != '\n'` doesn't make any sense. You don't have a `'\n'` at the end of your array, and even if you did, that would be a peculiar [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value), so that would keep on looping into oblivion until it found a `'\n'`.. that is if you were even updating `ptr` in the loop, which you're not. Instead you're checking `ptr[0] != '\n'` each iteration. You should loop thru all items in the array based on it's length, see my 2nd comment.

Comment: Ohhh, the int array doenst have a '\n'

Comment: @Neronimo, No, i don't see one, it would have the value 10, assuming you using a ASCII-compatible encoding (extremely likely). A `for`-loop instead of your `while`-loop in `main` would fit much better. I also think the `last_i` should not be part of the `for`-loop but only be part of the `while`-loop, maybe replace also this loop with a `for`-loop?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/M1Mh7nrf8 Printing now! Thx. Now gotta fix the sorting

Comment: @Neronimo Please don't post solutions this way. Either edit your questions and add the new code, in addition to the one you already posted (don't delete the old one). Or answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with our code. When you enable warnings you would see some of them but not all. If you are using gcc or clang, use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` to see them. Warnings can help you find problems and you should try to eliminate them (there are some special warnings which warn about harmless code, but not here).

`int* ptr = &numbers;` This declares `ptr` as a pointer to int. But you define it as `&numbers`, `numbers` is an array of pointer, when you use `numbers` it decays to a pointer (meaning you use it like a pointer most of the time, a exception is `sizeof`). This means `&numbers` is a pointer to an array of 10 that decays to a pointer to pointer. To solve that you can just write `int *ptr = numbers;` Now `ptr` points to the first element of `numbers`.

`sizeof` returns the size of an object in bytes. When `sizeof(int)!=1`, the result of `sizeof(numbers)` is more than the elements in `numbers`.

To your question in the title:

You didn't set any element in `numbers` to 10 or `'\n'`, assuming you use ASCII or some extension to ASCII. So the condition `*ptr != '\n'` for your `while`-loop is never false. The other problem is that `ptr` stays at the first element of `numbers` and you don't change it in the `while`-loop. So why should it stop with the while loop?

There are a lot more problems, but you can ask them in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- in the `sort` function, `last_i` should be initialized to `N - 1` instead of `N` as you access `ptr[i + 1]` in the inner loop.  As posted, the code has undefined behavior (a buffer overflow) that could cause an endless loop.
- `last_i--;` should be moved out of the inner loop.

Using `for` loops is less error prone:

```
void sort(int *ptr, int N) {
    for (int last_i = N - 1; last_i > 0; last_i--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < last_i; i++) {
            if (ptr[i] > ptr[i + 1]) {
                int temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                ptr[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```